# WP rest api is too slow on custom endpoints

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I've created my custom WP rest api to transfer data between my app and wordpress site.But each time the app sends any request (POST or GET), it takes between 5 to 7 seconds to response !!!!
That is really bad because no one uses such a this laggy and low speed app.
Any guides for solving this issue can be helpful.

**This is how I defined my app database:**

```
function seconddb() {
    global $seconddb;
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "databasename";
    $seconddb = new wpdb($username, $password, $dbname, $servername);
}
add_action('init', 'seconddb');
```

**And this is how I defined my custom endpoint:**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'mirzagate/v1', '/add/', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'app_db_insert',
    'permission_callback' => function ($request) {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $allowed_roles = array('administrator', 'subscriber' );
            if ( array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
               return true;
            }
     }
  ) );
} );

function app_db_insert( $newdata ) {
  $body = $newdata->get_body_params();
  $table = $newdata->get_param( 'table' );
  global $seconddb;
  if($seconddb->insert($table,$body)!=false){
      return "DataInserted";
  }
  else{
      return "DataNotInsertedError";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the connection to the 2nd database is causing the delay? Try to comment out the DB part and just return a simple "echo 'test';". Also, maybe it's a server performance issue?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I commented out the DB part.It took 2.12 seconds to response while the full function takes 2.5 seconds.
This web site is hosted on a shared hosting service.Does changing it to a VPS help the performance?

Comment: A dedicated server (VPS) should have a much higher performance than shared hosting.
Also, check your PHP version on the server, maybe it's an old version - the newer PHP versions have better performance as well.

Comment: @OfirBaruch The PHP version is 7.4.The site itself takes between 1.07 to 1.53 seconds to load whitch I think is OK for a complete load.But I don't know why the rest api should take more than 3 seconds.I'm looking for a way to decrease this delay,because I don't know how much it takes effect if I change shared hosting to VPS.